# Can't run simple intro langchain application and getting error

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

I'm having issues running simple example from the [langchain](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/getting_started/getting_started.html)

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv,find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

from langchain.llms import openai

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.9)
text = "What would be a good company name for a company that makes colorful socks?"
print(llm(text))
```

When I'm running it, I have an error below. Today in the morning the code was working fine, not sure what's happened

Could you please help ?

### '''

InvalidRequestError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[40], line 2
1 text = "What would be a good company name for a company that makes colorful socks?"
----> 2 print(llm(text))

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\base.py:291, in BaseLLM.**call**(self, prompt, stop, callbacks)
286 def **call**(
287     self, prompt: str, stop: Optional[List[str]] = None, callbacks: Callbacks = None
288 ) -> str:
289     """Check Cache and run the LLM on the given prompt and input."""
290     return (
--> 291         self.generate([prompt], stop=stop, callbacks=callbacks)
292         .generations[0][0]
293         .text
294     )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\base.py:191, in BaseLLM.generate(self, prompts, stop, callbacks)
189 except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception) as e:
190     run_manager.on_llm_error(e)
--> 191     raise e
192 run_manager.on_llm_end(output)
193 return output

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\base.py:185, in BaseLLM.generate(self, prompts, stop, callbacks)
180 run_manager = callback_manager.on_llm_start(
181     {"name": self.**class**.**name**}, prompts, invocation_params=params
182 )
183 try:
184     output = (
--> 185         self._generate(prompts, stop=stop, run_manager=run_manager)
186         if new_arg_supported
187         else self._generate(prompts, stop=stop)
188     )
189 except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception) as e:
190     run_manager.on_llm_error(e)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\openai.py:315, in BaseOpenAI._generate(self, prompts, stop, run_manager)
313     choices.extend(response["choices"])
314 else:
--> 315     response = completion_with_retry(self, prompt=_prompts, **params)
316     choices.extend(response["choices"])
317 if not self.streaming:
318     # Can't update token usage if streaming

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\openai.py:106, in completion_with_retry(llm, **kwargs)
102 @retry_decorator
103 def _completion_with_retry(**kwargs: Any) -> Any:
104     return llm.client.create(**kwargs)
--> 106 return _completion_with_retry(**kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tenacity_*init*_.py:289, in BaseRetrying.wraps..wrapped_f(*args, **kw)
287 @functools.wraps(f)
288 def wrapped_f(*args: t.Any, **kw: t.Any) -> t.Any:
--> 289     return self(f, *args, **kw)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tenacity_*init*_.py:379, in Retrying.**call**(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
377 retry_state = RetryCallState(retry_object=self, fn=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
378 while True:
--> 379     do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
380     if isinstance(do, DoAttempt):
381         try:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tenacity_*init*_.py:314, in BaseRetrying.iter(self, retry_state)
312 is_explicit_retry = fut.failed and isinstance(fut.exception(), TryAgain)
313 if not (is_explicit_retry or self.retry(retry_state)):
--> 314     return fut.result()
316 if self.after is not None:
317     self.after(retry_state)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py:438, in Future.result(self, timeout)
436     raise CancelledError()
437 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 438     return self.__get_result()
440 self._condition.wait(timeout)
442 if self._state in [CANCELLED, CANCELLED_AND_NOTIFIED]:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py:390, in Future.__get_result(self)
388 if self._exception:
389     try:
--> 390         raise self._exception
391     finally:
392         # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception
393         self = None

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tenacity_*init*_.py:382, in Retrying.**call**(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
380 if isinstance(do, DoAttempt):
381     try:
--> 382         result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
383     except BaseException:  # noqa: B902
384         retry_state.set_exception(sys.exc_info())  # type: ignore[arg-type]

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\openai.py:104, in completion_with_retry.._completion_with_retry(**kwargs)
102 @retry_decorator
103 def _completion_with_retry(**kwargs: Any) -> Any:
--> 104     return llm.client.create(**kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\completion.py:25, in Completion.create(cls, *args, **kwargs)
23 while True:
24     try:
---> 25         return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
26     except TryAgain as e:
27         if timeout is not None and time.time() > start + timeout:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py:149, in EngineAPIResource.create(cls, api_key, api_base, api_type, request_id, api_version, organization, **params)
127 @classmethod
128 def create(
129     cls,
(...)
136     **params,
137 ):
138     (
139         deployment_id,
140         engine,
141         timeout,
142         stream,
143         headers,
144         request_timeout,
145         typed_api_type,
146         requestor,
147         url,
148         params,
--> 149     ) = cls.__prepare_create_request(
150         api_key, api_base, api_type, api_version, organization, **params
151     )
153     response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
154         "post",
155         url,
(...)
160         request_timeout=request_timeout,
161     )
163     if stream:
164         # must be an iterator

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py:83, in EngineAPIResource.__prepare_create_request(cls, api_key, api_base, api_type, api_version, organization, **params)
81 if typed_api_type in (util.ApiType.AZURE, util.ApiType.AZURE_AD):
82     if deployment_id is None and engine is None:
---> 83         raise error.InvalidRequestError(
84             "Must provide an 'engine' or 'deployment_id' parameter to create a %s"
85             % cls,
86             "engine",
87         )
88 else:
89     if model is None and engine is None:

InvalidRequestError: Must provide an 'engine' or 'deployment_id' parameter to create a <class 'openai.api_resources.completion.Completion'>
'''

Answer (score 1):

From the traceback you provided, it looks like you're using an Azure API key:

> if typed_api_type in (util.ApiType.AZURE, util.ApiType.AZURE_AD): 82 if deployment_id is None and engine is None: ---> 83 raise error.InvalidRequestError.

LangChain has a separate `AzureOpenAI` class that handles the slightly different setup that comes with using Azure. Note that you need to have your own deployment instance on Azure, which you then reference when initializing your `llm` instance.

From [the docs](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/models/llms/integrations/azure_openai_example.html):

```
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI

# Create an instance of Azure OpenAI
# Replace the deployment name with your own
llm = AzureOpenAI(
    deployment_name="td2",
    model_name="text-davinci-002", 
)

llm("Tell me a joke")
```

Others who have encountered this issue seem to have found [a workaround](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/318#issuecomment-1490456382) by using the standard `langchain.llms.OpenAI` class but then passing in a custom `'engine'` parameter (instead of `'model'`).  But it looks like you don't need to tangle with that now that LC has an official Azure interface.

The [OpenAI Github documentation on Azure endpoints](https://github.com/openai/openai-python#microsoft-azure-endpoints) may also be of use here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with the code itself but with Jupyter notebook where I tried to start it. When i copied it into simple python file and ran via VSCode, everything worked well.